# Does concurrency in Python mean executing multiple functions at the same time?

Tags: python, concurrency

I have read through serval tutorials about concurrency in python and I also know the differences between concurrency and Parallelism, but I am still a little bit confused about the definition of concurrency.

Many people define concurrency as executing multiple `tasks` at the same time. I am wondering what are tasks in python. Are they functions? Can I say concurrency in Python is executing multiple functions at the same time?

Comment: "Concurrency" in general means that you can have two or more activities that have been started and not yet finished at the same time. "Parallelism" implies concurrency (i.e., you can't have two or more activities running in parallel if they are not also concurrent with each other.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Many people define concurrency as executing multiple `tasks` at the same time

The `tasks` here is not defined from the computer's view, but we human's view. As long as we can confirm things are not being served strictly in order(no one is blocking another), we can say they are happening concurrently.

> Can I say concurrency in Python is executing multiple functions at the same time?

There are plenty of ways to support concurrency in Python, executing multiple functions(via multi-threads or multi-processes) at the same time is absolutely one of them(actually this is parallelism), but not the only one.

Comment: If you want to get really computer-science-y, then a _task_ has a _start event_ and an _end event_, and two tasks are _concurrent_ if both of their start events happen before either of their end events happens. They define it in that way because a big part of  understsanding concurrency is understanding all of the different possible ways in which a set of events can be _[serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability)_